# Media Element js firefox and IE and full screen issues

Tags: mediaelement.js

I currently have various problems playing videos with the Media Element.js player. I've spent many hours trying to get it to work (searching stackoverflow for answers). To start off I have this problem on the page http://www.tomspianomusic.com/video.html (bottom page):

I can't get my videos to play in Firefox and IE. Chrome and safari (IOS) are ok.

First I added the correct MIME types to the server's .htaccess file (step 1) it's not RTF but generated through the control panel on the homepage:

```html
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Secondly I encoded the videos to the correct formats (mp4/webm/ogv). the markup on the page is such (note webm above mp4 due to playback issues in chrome):

```html
<video width="320" height="240" poster="images/HAPPINESS_poster.jpg" controls preload="none">
    <source type="video/webm" src="video/Happiness.webm" />
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/Happiness.mp4" />
    <source type="video/ogg" src="video/Happiness.ogv" />
    <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;poster=myvideo.jpg&amp;file=video/Happiness.mp4" />        
        <img src="images/HAPPINESS_poster.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
    </object>
</video>
```

In Firefox the video won't load BUT I can play the video through the direct link on the site . I'm running in circles and going crazy! Can someone please help? It must still be a MIME issue I believe but I think I've done everything that was asked!

Secondly when viewing the videos on a large desktop screen (21 inch plus) the videos won't expand to the full screen. It will on fill about 60% of the screen. Any idea's where that problem could be? (Note I am not a master at javascript).

Thank you for your time.